# Can we auto hide parameters in ssrs based on the parameter selected

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

When i select a parameter1 value i want a parameter2 to hide for few selected parameter1 values.

for suppose : if parameter1 has 1 to 8 values. I wanted parameter2 to be displayed only when i select 2,4,6 values.

Is this possible in SSRS?

Comment: Just don't use the parameter2 based on the parameter1 value. You will skip the parameter2 even if user selects a value for it.

Comment: Even parameter value is required. Default value would be ALL for parameter2 whereas when not hidden we can select from drop down.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't have expressions for manipulating hidden properties of parameters in report manager.